# Submit action form

Tags: php, admin, magento2

when i submit form don't submit to acion Save. what wrong.

**Source**

```
<div class="edit-slide">
<?php $model = $this->getModelEdit();?>
    <form id="edit_form_slideshow" method="post" action="<?php echo  $this->getUrl('*/*/save'); ?>">
        <input type="text" hidden " name="slideshow_id" value="<?php echo $model -> getId(); ?>">
        <div class="admin__field field field-title  required _required">
            <label class="label admin__field-label"> Name</label>
            <div class="admin__field-control control">
                <input type="text" class="" name="name" value="<?php echo $model -> getName(); ?>">
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div class="admin__field field field-title  required _required">
            <label class="title  admin__field-label"> Create at: </label>
            <label class="create-at"> <?php echo $model -> getCreated_at();  ?></label>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__field field field-title  required _required">
            <label class="title  admin__field-label"> Update at:</label>
            <label class="update-at"> <?php echo $model -> getUpdated_at();  ?></label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save">
        <a href="<?php echo  $this->getUrl('*/*/delete',['_current' => true] ); ?>">Delete</a>

    </form>
</div>
```

I tested

```
 <a href=" <?php echo  $this->getUrl('*/*/save'); ?>"> Save </a> is true
```

**I Edited**

```
 <update handle="formkey"/> in layout
```

Comment: what is your action  url?

Comment: namespace Xanka\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slideshow;

class Save extends \Xanka\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slideshow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For admin form submissions you have to use `form_key` or else it will not save the data and it'll redirect to the dashboard page.

**For Magento 1.x :**

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Thanks to @xanka

### Edit:

**For Magento 2 :**

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

Add this code inside your form.

Comment: Thanks  @MeenakshiSundaram R.
but in magento2 has to be:
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />